# MVC 5 DropDownListFor not selecting value and ModelState always goes false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been currently working on MVC course exercises from the Pluralsight. I got this DropDownList with 4 elements nested but it's impossible to select one and see it actually selected in the View.

[Drop Down List img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rxyP.png)

```
@model GigHub.ViewModels.GigFormViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Gigs"))
{
    <p class="alert alert-info">All fields are <strong>required</strong></p>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Venue)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Venue, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Venue)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "15 Aug 1995" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Time)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Time, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "20:30" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Time)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Genre)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genre, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), new {@class = "form-control"})
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
}
@section scripts
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I've tried tried removing the "form-control" class from the passed arguments and after that, it's actually possible to select Genre but even after that, after submitting, the ModelState always goes false.

Controller:

```
using GigHub.Models;
using GigHub.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GigHub.Controllers
{
    public class GigsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public GigsController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        // GET: Gigs
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var viewModel = new GigFormViewModel
            {
                Genres = _context.Genres.ToList()
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(GigFormViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                viewModel.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();
                return View("Create", viewModel);
            }
            var gig = new Gig
            {
                ArtistId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                DateTime = viewModel.GetDateTime(),
                GenreId = viewModel.Genre,
                Venue = viewModel.Venue
            };

            _context.Gigs.Add(gig);
            _context.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using GigHub.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace GigHub.ViewModels
{
    public class GigFormViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Venue { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [FutureDate]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ValidTime]
        public string Time { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Genre { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

        public DateTime GetDateTime() => DateTime.Parse($"{Date}{Time}");
    }
}
```

I spent hours on it and I'm already running out of ideas.

Comment: Remove `[Required]` from `IEnumerable<Genre> Genres`

Comment: Stephen Muecke has got it.  You are not posting back your collection of Genres, so your model state would never be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove [Required] from IEnumerable Genres

Thank you guys very much. It's already adding a new row into the DB. The only thing that has left is that, the Genre doesn't appear in View, but that's for another concern. Thanks :)